# How do you cast a pointer to a character without using an ampersand?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, ampersand

For a project, I need to cast and make pointer from an int into a char **to perform a byte switch** on the hex values. The only caveat is that I'm not allowed to use the ampersand.

So I have it working with this line of code:

```
int x = 5000;
char * ptr = (char *)&x;
```

But obviously I need to find a way to cast this pointer without using the ampersand. Does anyone know of a way to do this? I've been searching and haven't found a way that doesn't involve using the ampersand or other operators I'm not allowed to use (|,[,], <<, >>, ^).

Comment: `&` is not a bit operator here.

Comment: It specifically says you cannot use &.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it just mistakes the function of & for being a bit operator.

Comment: Then you should clarify your question.

Comment: Your question says you cannot use bit operators "*except for the pointer notation*".  `&x` is pointer notation (and it's not really an exception anyway because the '`&`' is not a bit operator in that context).

Comment: why are you not allowed to use the operator essential in retrieving the address of a memory cell? are you trying to make your own compiler or something?

Comment: You can perform a byte switch without using `&` (if you also make some assumptions about the representation)

Comment: Maybe something could be done with the varargs version, @chux, but the `char *` version will result in a pointer whose *value* is derived from `x`, not the needed pointer to the *location* of `x`.

Comment: The project says: You cannot use bit operators. 5. You cannot use bit operators (e.g. <<, >>, **&**, |, ^)

Comment: So, address-of is not actually covered...

Comment: maybe this was a question better answered by your teacher then...not stackoverflow

Comment: You have to use some common sense here.  The question as posed is a challenging puzzle for advanced C programmers.  If you are taking an Advanced C Puzzles class, then yes, the teacher probably doesn't want you using `&` to take the address of something.  If you are in an introductory C course, however, then I'm sure the intention is that you actually can use `&` in the address-of context, and you'll look ridiculous using any of the answers posted here.

Comment: You're really not allowed to use `[` and `]` ?

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey As the post seems obfuscated, using trigraphs/digraphs seems appropriate for an obfuscated answer: `??(` for `[` and `??)` for `]`.  Alas, no trigraph/digraph for `&`.

Comment: @chux: Sorry, I'm taking a very dim view of all this. Who gives a hoot?

Answer (score 8):

Make a union.

```
union myUnion {
  int x;
  char c[4];
} u;

char* ptr = u.c;
u.x = 5000;
```

Comment: Maybe `char c ??( 4 ??);` (`[` and `]` are not allowed, says the question, but it's unclear anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Swapping bytes for `sizeof(int)==2` and `CHAR_BIT==8` and 2s-complement without bit-operations or address-of:

```
int swapbytes(int i) {
    return (signed)( (unsigned)i / 256 + (unsigned)i * 256);
}
```

So, absolutely **no need to get a pointer**.

Comment: This assumes a 2-byte `int`.  Arithmetic operators can be used for larger `int` as well, but it gets more complex and may also need `%`.

Comment: @Dmitri: Yes, but the point of the answer was that it works, and how. Not providing pastable code.

Comment: This might be the closest thing here to what the assignment (?) is actually looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, & is not a bitwise operator in that usage. The ampersand character is just overloaded for two completely different purposes (address-of and bitwise AND). Similarly, in C++, when you write **cout<<"\n";** you're not doing a bit-shift.

Second, you can easily cast an integer to a pointer in this manner:

```
 long l=0x8000;       //I read the datasheet and saw that there's a buffer at 0x8000...
 void*p = (void*) l;
```

Is it possible, though, to get the address of a C variable without using the ampersand? Well, I wouldn't rule that out. You might be able to do something with the fact that the name of an array returns an address even if you don't use &, e.g.

```
int a[40];      
printf("%d\n",a);  //Prints an address
printf("%d\n",&a); //Prints the same address
```

Answer (score 0):

As by your requirements no `|`, `[]`, `<<`, `>>`, `^`, and `&` (assuming both dereference and bitwise AND):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 5000;
    char *ptr;

    /* magic steps begin
     * (DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION CODE, PROTECT YOUR ENVIRONMENT, etc.) */
    int *x_helper = malloc(sizeof *x_helper);
    *x_helper = x;
    ptr = (char *) x_helper;
    /* magic steps end */

    return 0;
}
```